# 'Control.CreateGraphics()' is a method, which is not valid in the given context in C#

Tags: c#

So I got a method which allows me to resize a label depending on the value of another one. Basically there is a label with a result and next to it is the "KB" label. Example: 30000 KB

So I've created this to methods:

```
public void UpdateSizeKB()
{
    lblKB.Show();
    lblResultKB.Width = GetLabelsSize(lblResultKB.Text);
    lblKB.Left = lblResultKB.Left + lblResultKB.Width + 5;
}

public int GetLabelsSize(string text)
{
    return lblResultKB.CreateGraphics.MeasureString(text, lblResultKB.Font).Width() + lblResultKB.Margin.Left + lblResultKB.Margin.Right;
}
```

And I will call the `UpdateSizeKB()` on the form. So every time the `lblResultKB` changes the `lblKB` will change it places.

But the function `GetLabelsSize` actually is not working very well because it displays an error on `CreateGraphics` called:

> 'Control.CreateGraphics()' is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Do you guys have any solution for this problem? Be able to make this work

Comment: Well, you're not calling it like a method, you're trying to access it like a field or property. Most likely you want something akin to `using (var g = lblResultKB.CreateGraphics()) { return g.MeasureString(...); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a pair of parentheses after `CreateGraphics`:

```
public int GetLabelsSize(string text)
{
    return (int)(lblResultKB.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(text, lblResultKB.Font).Width + lblResultKB.Margin.Left + lblResultKB.Margin.Right);
}
```

i.e. you'll actually have to *call* the `CreateGraphics()` method to acquire a `Graphics` object, not try to access an attribute of the method. :)

However, it's good practice to use an `using` block with `Graphics` objects, since they wrap unmanaged resources, so:

```
public int GetLabelsSize(string text)
{
    using (var g = lblResultKB.CreateGraphics()) {
       return (int)(g.MeasureString(text, lblResultKB.Font).Width + lblResultKB.Margin.Left + lblResultKB.Margin.Right);
    }
}
```

Comment: But then the `.Width()` will display an error too: Non-invocable member 'SizeF.Width' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Because it isn't a method... it's a property.

Comment: @LeugimSnitram Fixed that in the example.

Comment: If I take out the parentheses it will say: Cannot implicity convert type 'float' to 'int'

Comment: @LeugimSnitram So cast it into an int. (Added that in the example, too.)